# Access token cached when using nuxtServerInit

Tags: nuxt.js, akamai

I'm having an authorization (JWT) related caching issue when using Nuxt.

This is the `nuxtServerInit` action, where I set the access token:

```js
// store/index.js

import cookie from 'cookie';

export const state = () => ({
  authCookie: 'MyAuthCookie',
});

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch, commit, state }, { req }) {
    // Check for access token
    const accessToken = req.headers.cookie &&
      cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie)[state.authCookie];

    // Set the access token, if there is one
    if (accessToken) {
      commit('auth/setAccessToken', accessToken);
    }
  },
};
```

The `accessToken` state is later used to set the `Authorization` header for all future requests in this plugin:

```js
// plugins/axios.js

export default function ({ app, store }) {
  app.$axios.onRequest((config) => {
    // Set the `Authorization` header for future requests if we're logged in
    if (store.getters['auth/isLoggedIn']) {
      config.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${store.state.auth.accessToken}`;
    }
  });
};
```

Nuxt stores data shared between client and server in a global `window.__NUXT__` variable in an inlined `<script>` tag, and because I am aggressively caching the page in question (using Akamai), the access token will never be updated.

Is there a better way of handling this, and to prevent the access token from being cached? Or in other words how do I prevent the `accessToken` state to be written to the global `__NUXT__` variable?

Comment: Could you use asyncData per page to set the AccessToken on each pageload client side?

Comment: Same issue here- did you ever find a resolution? This is a big security issue as it can cause people's credentials to be cached server side :(

Comment: @NickBarrett No, unfortunately. Yes, that was/is our exact issue. We ended up caching everything except the page itself.

Comment: @jdlm Yeah fair enough- we have opted to include the headers on non-authenticated requests but leave them off for authenticated ones.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding below the header on each request so it will not cache headers

```
config.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate';
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is not with the headers, but with the access token being stored in a `<script>` tag in the HTML.

Comment: Just Curious... Why you storing the access token in a script tag

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying *not* to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is filling the store on both, server and client side.

Server side is already covered with nuxtServerInit.

Client side could be done with a client side plugin, like described here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/4573#issuecomment-557857101

Answer (score 0):

I come up with the similar problem. in my case, I login, then route byside, when I route back with the browser's go back button, the question appears, i.e. within nuxtServerInit, req.headers.cookie can't be read correctly.
I find out it's because the document is read from browser's disk cache. so , updated cookies can't be read out.
so, I forbiden document cache within nuxtServerInit, and it worked out

```js
async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch, commit, state }, { req, res }) {
    // forbid browser cache html document
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
    res.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    
    
    // Check for access token
    const accessToken = req.headers.cookie &&
      cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie)[state.authCookie];

    // Set the access token, if there is one
    if (accessToken) {
      commit('auth/setAccessToken', accessToken);
    }
  }
```